# Conditional Division in Stata

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
  year      Gender        VP
                
  2023      Total           3                  
  2023       F              2            
  2023       M              1            
  2022      Total           6                 
  2022       F              4                  
  2022       M              2               
  2021      Total           2                
  ...
```

What I want to do is generate a variable `VP_per` that gives me the female percentage of VPs for every year.

Basically something that looks like

`bysort year gender : gen VP_per = VP if gender==1 / VP if gender==2`

where 1 is the numeric value for Female and 2 is the numeric value for Total.

Comment: do you have any code of what you tried?

Comment: Note that your code is illegal and some distance from what you need too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data layout -- in which subtotals are held in separate observations -- is not especially suitable for most Stata purposes, but it can be accommodated.

Here is some technique, which can be modified for numeric variables with value labels.

```
clear 
input int Year str5 Gender byte VP
2023 "Total" 3
2023 "F"     2
2023 "M"     1
2022 "Total" 6
2022 "F"     4
2022 "M"     2
end

* this hinges on sorting F M Total 
bysort Year (Gender) : gen wanted = 100 * VP[1] / VP[3] 

* need to modify for numeric variables 
egen num = total(cond(Gender == "F", VP, .)), by(Year)
egen den = total(cond(Gender == "Total", VP, .)), by(Year) 
gen wanted2 = 100 * num/den
```

If `Gender` were numeric with 1 for Female and 2 for Total

```
egen num = total(cond(Gender == 1, VP, .)), by(Year)
egen den = total(cond(Gender == 2, VP, .)), by(Year)
```