# Drawing percentage graphs without percent variables

Tags: graph, stata, catplot

I have a dataset in Stata that looks like the following :

| Year | Gender | Presidents | Presidents_F | Presidents_M | Presidents_Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | Male | 5 | 6 | 5 | 11 |
| 2023 | Female | 6 | 6 | 5 | 11 |
| 2023 | Total | 11 | 6 | 5 | 11 |
| 2022 | Male | 3 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2022 | Female | 2 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2022 | Total | 5 | 2 | 3 | 5 |

I want to be able to draw stacked graphs that show the percentage share of female and male presidents (sum to 100) over years (dataset goes from 1970 to 2023) without generating separate percentage variables but using the absolute numbers already available.

I earlier tried generating line graphs from percentage variables and that worked well in showing the trends. However, my supervisor wants me to not generate additional unnecessary variables but still be able to graph the percentages across years.

She suggested using `catplot` but I am unsure how `catplot` can give be the ability to define the formula for the percentage within the command.

Please suggest the best way to go forward.

Comment: This is your third thread. It's good practice here to react to an answer -- by accepting it or by explaining why it falls short of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data already show considerable redundancy. You don't cite your previous threads  in which I advised (twice over) against keeping totals in separate observations.

[Conditional Division in Stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76464794/conditional-division-in-stata)

[Is there a way to calculate percentages comparing observations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77097730/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-percentages-comparing-observations)

`catplot` (from SSC, as you are asked to explain) can give you stacked bars, using its `percent()` option, but the redundancy of showing two complementary percentages can be avoided by using a line graph of either one.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input int year str6 gender byte(presidents presidents_f presidents_m presidents_total)
2023 "Male"    5 6 5 11
2023 "Female"  6 6 5 11
2023 "Total"  11 6 5 11
2022 "Male"    3 2 3  5
2022 "Female"  2 2 3  5
2022 "Total"   5 2 3  5
end

catplot gender year if inlist(gender, "Male", "Female") [fw=presidents],  percent(year) asyvars stack

bysort year (gender) : gen pcfemale = 100 * presidents[1] / presidents[3] 
levelsof year, local(years)
line pcfemale year , ytitle(% female presidents) xla(`years')
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. The structure of the data is based on what we received from the database. The response you posted makes sense but defeats the purpose of not generating percentage variables. Is there a way for me to say generate a line graph of percentage shares without actually generating percentage share variables independently?

Comment: Even if we were to ignore the columns on Gender and Presidents, and base our graph on the columns Presidents_F, Presidents_M, and Presidents_Total and year, is there a way for me to specify the formula function within the graphing command without generating new variables in the dataset ?

Comment: You're asking the same question repeatedly, `catplot` has inbuilt percent options so that it shows percents in the graph: variables are created but they only exist temporarily.  If a command doesn't offer such options, there isn't a different syntax.  A goal of not having unnecessary variables isn't satisfied by your existing data structure which is highly redundant already.